# Next.js display queries with Apollo Client at Page.jsx

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm here to ask how to display my query from Graphql on my `page.jsx`, it's a page with individual content.
My query looks like this:

```js
query NewQuery($slug: String!) {
      pageBy(id: "", pageId: 10) {
        id
      }
      postBy(slug: $slug) {
        blocksJSON
        title
        featuredImage {
          node {
            mediaItemUrl
            mediaDetails {
              width
              height
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I am working with Apollo Client and I can't find any answer on the internet.

I tried this approach, but it didn't work as expected. Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this?

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot is not really comprehensive, I would suggest next time to add code snippets. It helps to have a wider perspective on your code. As it is I will make some assumptions on your setup, so might not be fully accurate.

As for the query. Your Page.jsx is a react component, as such it needs to have a function component in it, that will return a JSX at the end for the client browser. From this function component you need it add a the the apollo client query and you will have access to the returned info in the "data" variable. Please see the example, and let me know how it worked out.

```
const Page = () => {
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY);
   
return <div>{loading ? <div>loading...</div> : <div> {data} </div>}</div>;
};

export default Page;
```

And also please do check out the library documentation since there are other steps involved as well, it us usually helpful.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started